# Is there a Form event like "Shown" but runs the code every time it is displayed instead of the just first time?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Just noticed in one of my programs that the form event `Shown` only runs the code when the form is first displayed. Every other time after that it does not run the code. Is there a form event that does what shown does, but every time it is displayed instead of just the first? Or is there a way to get around it? This is the exact same for the `Load` event too.

Thanks heaps, appreciate any response.

Comment: Without having tested at all, I would assume that you could handle `VisibleChanged` and test that `Visible` is `True`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney cool thanks, will test that now.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I can't see a `.visible` property after typing out the form name. I can just ignore the validation check. I just tested it without the validation check, and I still get the same result as I would with the shown event

Comment: Why would you be typing the form name?  Surely the code is in the form itself so it would be `Me.Visible` or just `Visible`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney still the same problem. Must be something to do with my code. I did use just `visible` also.

Comment: To get the behaviour you describe, you'd have to be displaying the form by calling `Show` and then hiding it rather than closing it. In most cases, it's more appropriate to close the form and then create another instance when you need to show it again, in which case you get the `Load` and `Shown` events raised again anyway. Is there a good reason not to do that in your case?

Comment: @jmcilhinney so when I load a form from my main form another form loads, it loads settings which changes that forms back colour. After closing the second form by clicking the red "X" on the window, and reopening it through the main form. The colours don't change. Could be a code problem though. But I think it's related to events because the Microsoft documentation says that load and shown events are called on the first display.

Comment: I would think that the `BackColor` of that form would be stored somewhere, e.g. `My.Settings`, and then loaded every time you display an instance of that form type.  If you create a new instance every time then the `Load` event will be raised each time and you can get that value each time.

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes it's stored in `My.Settings`. Tried `Load` event just then, colour changes the first time it's shown but not subsequentially. It just sets the form backcolour = to the My.Settings variable.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. If we don't see your code, we can't know what's wrong with it. I'd probably suggest a new question because you're getting away from the originally specified topic.

Comment: @jmcilhinney yeah I will now, just thought the problem was with the events not the code. Thanks for your assistance

Comment: The [`Form.Activated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated(v=vs.110).aspx) might be useful for this, though it might fire off a little *too* often.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested with this in `Form1`:

```
Private f2 As New Form2

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    f2.Show()
End Sub
```

and this in `Form2`:

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MessageBox.Show("Form2_Load")
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_VisibleChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.VisibleChanged
    If Visible Then
        MessageBox.Show("Form2_VisibleChanged")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Hide()
End Sub
```

and it worked exactly as expected.  Every time I clicked `Button1` in `Form1`, `Form2` was displayed.  The first time I saw messages for "Form2_Load"and "Form2_VisibleChanged" and on subsequent occasions on for "Form2_VisibleChanged".